# Determine whether the following sets are vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to make sure that I'm correct with my answers to whether these three sets are vector spaces or not:

- **A** = $\{(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4: a +5c +d = 0\}$
- **B** = $\{ f \in C[0,1]: f(0) =1\}$
- **C** = $\{ f \in C[-1,1]: \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \ dx = 0\}$

---

**A** is a vector space because it's a subspace to $\mathbb{R}^4$ (a vector space) and it satisfies that vector addition and scalar multiplication generates vectors inside of the same subspace. It's also given that the zero vector is part of the set.

**B** is not a vector space because the zero-function is not an element in the set.

**C** is a vector space because $F(x)=0$ on the interval [-1,1] implies that $f(x)=0$ somewhere on that interval. Continuous functions have well defined function addition and scalar multiplication so we know that it satisfies the conditions for a subspace of a vector space.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  This is generally good.  For **C**, is F the definite integral?  You should probably mention that the sum of two functions whose integral is zero also has integral zero (and this works for scalar multiples too)

Comment: Yes, I meant the definite integral when I included the interval, but maybe I should write that explicitly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, very good except that the argument in **C** needs a little attention. When you say "f(x)=0  somewhere on that interval" I assume you wanted to say "the zero function has zero integral". There is of course a world of difference between being zero at one point and being identically zero on an interval.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "zero function has zero integral". I get that there is a difference between zero at one point and zero at all points, but do we require that there is a function that $f(x)=0 \forall x$ or is $f(x_1)=0$ for some $x_1 \in [-1,1]$ sufficient?

Comment: Because the vector space is closed under scalar multiplication it is closed under multiplication by $0$ and therefore the function which is identically zero must be in the space.

Comment: In general  all you ever need is to prove that $au+bv$ is in the space for all scalars a,b and vectors u,v since that includes the case of $0\times u$.

Comment: I think I got it now. The zero function $f(x)=0$ satisfies the integral so the set is a vector space given vector addition and scalar multiplication also holds.

Comment: Yes - this is an important idea to get right,